# Total Sum for Table Columns & JQuery Live Search

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've integrated the total sum for the table columns and it works great. The same page has a JQuery live search. When I do a search, the results appear just fine but the total sum is showing the total for all data not the filtered data by JQuery Search.

Now, we want the total sum to change upon doing a search to show only the filtered results. So on doing a search, table data will be filtered and accordingly, the total sum amounts will be recalculated based on the filtered results.

I've tried to disable the live search capability so the page will reload each time I do a search. And accordingly, the total sums will be recalculated. But I couldn't get it to work like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('table thead th').each(function(i)
{
calculateColumn(i);
});
});
function calculateColumn(index)
{
var total = 0;
$('table tr').each(function()
{
var value = parseInt($('td', this).eq(index).text());
if (!isNaN(value))
{
total += value;
}
}); 
$('table tfoot td').eq(index).text('' + total);
}
</script>

<tfoot>
    <tr class="sum" height="50px">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: First, Welcome to stackoverflow. Second, Can you add more clear details about your problem ?

Comment: I use the above code to calculate column total. The problem is when I do a search in this table using jquery search box, the page doesn't reload. instead, it loads the search results in the same page. That is fine but the calculated total is based on all the columns and not the newly filtered columns.

Say I have A, B, C values in a column. Total will be ABC. Let's say I searched for something that shows only A and B. Still the total is ABC and not affected by this search query.

Comment: Try calling the calculation function after executing the filtering one